# import list of pcs using import-Csv and change attribute using powershell script

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, scripting, csv

Im trying to write a `powershell` script to change attribute called "`comment`" in a list of pcs using  `csv` and `import-Csv`.

[image]

Here is my script

```
$computers=Import-Csv -Path "C:\sds.csv" 
foreach ($item in $computers){ 
Set-ADComputer -identity $computers.DistinguishedName -add @{comment="bara"}
}
```

and hear is my `csv` file located under `"C:\sds.csv"`

[image]

But it jumps in to this ..

[image]

Tried googling and changing here and there, yet does not work! I have very little understanding of power-shell script, yet wish to learn. Can someone guide me please what im messing up ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `for`, you must work on the current item and not from the `computers` collection.
So you must change in your command `computers` by `item` :

```
Set-ADComputer -identity $item.DistinguishedName -add @{comment="bara"}
```

Comment: Fantastic :) it worked